# Twig tests VS php tests

Tags: twig, php-5.5

I have to work with an array of information extracted from a database and I want to display each part of this array according to a criterion, so it is better to make the test in the PHP or in the Twig template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on a couple of things:

1. the complexity of the test
2. The number of places you need to execute this test logic in.

If it's just something like a simple comparison like `{{ product.color == 'red' ? 'love' : 'hate' }}` then you should most likely put it in the twig template itself. If it is more complex it's best to put it in PHP code to keep it readable and thus separate the layout from the logic.

If you need to do this test in more than a couple of places you should also put it in a PHP object method and use that in all of those places. That way you do not have to change the `'red'` color in multiple places if you'd ever want to change it.